# Caffeine vs Nicotine addiction

Tags: caffeine

We, who love coffee very much, have a belief that coffee(which has caffeine) is better than cigarette or any other products which has nicotine. But as far as I know caffeine isn't so good for the body too. Is caffeine is less harmful than nicotine? Is there any comparative analysis on this?

Comment: While I appreciate the question in concept, it doesn't belong on [coffee.se] since it is really about [alkaloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaloid) (caffeine and nicotine) and not coffee. Consider [health.se] or even [chemistry.se] for more.

Comment: Well thanks for appreciation... coffee contains caffeine. As we love coffee and discuss about coffee here, I wanted to know the harmful effect of caffeine. If its not the right platform to ask then its ok to hold the question. Any way thanks @hoc_age

Comment: I take your point. However, your primary question is, "Is caffeine [...] less harmful than nicotine?" [coffee.se] considers questions *primarily about coffee* on-topic; conversely, questions primarily about caffeine (or other caffeine-containing drinks, etc.) are not on-topic. See [this Coffee meta](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/q/108) for more about our current stance, and weigh in if you'd like! If you were to contrast cigarettes (which contain nicotine) with coffee (which contains caffeine), then I would say conventional consumption of coffee is not likely to cause lung cancer...!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a study where cocaine addicts were given IV nicotine or caffeine in comparable amounts:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11160635

Basically, both drugs showed roughly equal good/bad effects, patient liking, and stimulation, but nicotine caused most of the patients' heart rates to increase, while caffeine caused them to decrease. This particular article doesn't have much bearing on non-cocaine addicts, but it's the most reputable I could find that directly compared the two.

Most scientists agree that 1-3 cups of coffee a day isn't that bad for most people, especially if you take it black (no sugar, non-dairy substitutes, and other bad stuff).

http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/caffeine/art-20045678

On the other hand, nicotine, while possibly not terrible in small quantities on its own, tends to be packaged with serious health concerns (eg smoking